# Static site generator based upon directories & files

Tags: ruby, web

I am looking for a nice way to generate a nested site structure in ruby. I want something that I can propose to clients instead of msword documents. Something of the form:

```
Home/
  index.txt
  About.txt
  Services/
    index.txt
    products.txt
    blahblah.txt
```

with the .txt files being markdown, or whatever.

I actually want to import this into a cms system, and just want to hook into whichever static-site generator that I can use.

Otherwise I will do it myself, but it would be nice to use something else for  integration with html preprocessors etc.

Comment: Something like http://pagegen.phnd.net/ looks like what I want, but in ruby if possible

Comment: Bonsai looks to be something like I want, although with yaml templating, this can modified.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/)

Comment: Thanks,

Jekyll doesn't appear to support the site structure I want. i want mere mortals to be able to generated their nested site structure (directories and files), files & folders is the simplest approach for mere mortals imho.

Comment: +1 for this -- Jekyll IS pretty much what you're looking for, as far as i can tell...

Answer (score 3):

there is also [middleman](http://rubygems.org/gems/middleman) for generating static sites

Comment: I also *love* Middleman. The only thing I don't like though is that I have failed to use the blog extension in a way that is sensible. In fact, out of frustration I started my own Middleman clone (Monkeyman), which is Scala based, so I understand it as well. ;-)

Comment: guys, how to setup so that Middleman can grab .sass and convert to .css? I use the HTML5 Boilerplate template and nothing happens. I need it for Haml too.

Answer (score 3):

How about either of

- [Ace](http://blog.101ideas.cz/posts/ace-static-site-generator.html)
- [nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/)
- [webby](http://webby.rubyforge.org/) or
- [StaticMatic](http://staticmatic.rubyforge.org/)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a gist featuring the most popular ones: https://gist.github.com/2254924

Comment: Nice gist! You will like even even better when [rendered this way](http://gist.io/2254924). :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest of those I have seen is Stacey, though it does not run static content, it generates it on the fly, and its in PHP, but yeah **it's just files and folders**, even if you drop images or videos or pdf's on the folder they will be managed and added automatically. And they are just .txt files. http://www.staceyapp.com/

But, if I had to choose a static compiler in Ruby I'd go with nanoc. It's the most powerful and flexible I've seen and once you configure it with the rules and such, it's just files and folders too.

There is also Stasis, I haven't tried it but it seems pretty good.

http://stasis.me/

Answer (score 0):

[**Monkeyman**](https://github.com/wspringer/monkeyman/) (Scala) supports markdown and SCAML, the Scala version of SCAML. It will basically copies and transforms a folder structure, in any way you like. Without any processing it will copy the structure as is, but it has a slew of decorators that not only are able to transform the content, but also the location to anything you like.

It doesn't support compass, SASS or any of that yet (although being based on Scalate, it probably does transform coffeescript embedded into the template pages, but I haven't tried that.)

Answer (score 0):

[DocPad](http://docpad.org/) works quite well. It supports a broad range of preprocessors.

Answer (score 0):

Let's check my open source [static file CMS](https://sphido.org/) it's taken markdown or HTML files from directory structure and generates HTML files.

It's written in Nodejs ([source codes](https://github.com/sphido/sphido)) and it's very flexible - you can choose to use React, Nunjucks or plain javascript for templates